# Webhook stop working after rename Bitbucket repo

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I've setup Bitbucket webhook to triger Jenkins job by using [bitbucket-push-and-pull-request plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-push-and-pull-request/) and work as I need.

I had to rename the repository in BitBucket settings, then change the url in the jenkins job and run the build manualy in order to check the new settings.

Webhook stop working and does not trigger the jenkins job anymore.
I've try to create new webhook in bitbucket and new jenkins job but still don't work.

If I rename the repo to the old name webhook work again.

Any idea how to solve this issue? (We're using Bitbucket server)